# When using components packaged with Lit, there is no property auto-completion when referenced as an npm package in a Vue project

Tags: vuejs3, vite, lit

When using components packaged with Lit, even though I've added TypeScript types, there is no property auto-completion when referenced as an npm package in a Vue project. Hovering the mouse over it does show the type definitions. How can I resolve this issue with editor suggestions? The code for my component types is as follows:

```
import '../base-icon/base-icon';
export declare enum ButtonSize {
    Large = "large",
    Default = "default",
    Small = "small"
}
export declare enum ButtonType {
    Default = "default",
    Primary = "primary"
}
declare const BaseButton_base: typeof import("lit").LitElement;
export declare class BaseButton extends BaseButton_base {
    /**
     * 按钮尺寸
     */
    size: ButtonSize;
    /**
     * 按钮类型
     */
    type: ButtonType;
    /**
     * 是否为朴素按钮
     * 为朴素按钮时按钮样式固定,type无效
     */
    plain: boolean;
    /**
     * 是否禁用
     * 禁用时按钮样式固定,type和plain无效
     */
    disabled: boolean;
    /**
     * 按钮图标
     */
    icon: string;
    render(): import("lit").TemplateResult<1>;
    private onClick;
}
export {};
```

During development, it is possible to have smart property suggestions, and warnings are provided when the types of the properties passed are incorrect.